# Enterprise library logging Database trace listener with custom parameter input

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, enterprise-library

I have log table in oracle DB and the supportting stored proc which takes following inputs and feds them to the table which have the same columns.

```
PROCEDURE     SP_LOG_INSERT
   ( ProgramDate  Varchar2  ,
     ProgramName   date ,
     ProgramStatus varchar2,
     ProgramMessage varachar2(4000 Byte))
```

how do i fill the table using these custom parameters using enterprise libaray 5.0. I have seen many online pages but most of them suggest to create a new table and new stored procedure I even refereed the blog by Alex Oliveri [here](http://alexfgo-en.blogspot.com/2012/06/ultimate-guide-for-enterprise-library.html) which was really helpful. But I want to use the existing table and stored procedure. Is it possible to do so or should i create a new table and stored procedure. Below is my TextFormatter

```
<formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either need to create a custom trace listener that knows how to log to your table/stored procedure or modify the logging table/stored procedure to be in a format that Enterprise Library expects.

Here is a [sample database trace listener](https://randylevy.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EntLib5Samples/CustomDatabaseTraceListener/Readme.txt) for SQL Server. It could be a good starting point for you if you decide to create a custom trace listener.

Also, since you are using Oracle you will need to change the database script (since it is SQL Server specific).  The [Ultimate guide for Enterprise Library 5.0 Application Logging Block using Oracle 11g](http://alexfgo-en.blogspot.com/2012/06/ultimate-guide-for-enterprise-library.html) is a good blog posting about setting up database logging with Oracle.